# Повторить запрос GET

Tags: curl, get, https, powershell

Впервые столкнулся с проблемой: необходимо повторить запрос браузера программным методом.
Пробовал `PowerShell`, `Curl`.

Ссылка:

```
https://is-node3.fssp.gov.ru/ajax_search?callback=jQuery3400961761604239515_1663428296297&system=ip&is%5Bextended%5D=1&nocache=1&is%5Bvariant%5D=3&is%5Bregion_id%5D%5B0%5D=-1&is%5Blast_name%5D=&is%5Bfirst_name%5D=&is%5Bdrtr_name%5D=комета&is%5Bip_number%5D=75286%2F21%2F02068-ИП&is%5Bpatronymic%5D=&is%5Bdate%5D=&is%5Baddress%5D=&is%5Bid_number%5D=&is%5Bid_type%5D%5B0%5D=&is%5Bid_issuer%5D=&is%5Binn%5D=&_=1663428296310
```

В браузере открывается верно, отдаёт javascript. При попытке открыть программно(код ниже) отдаёт `html` страницу.

Во время запроса повторяются все заголовки.

В чём может быть проблема?

P.S. Понимаю что парсить не хорошо, но они отключили официальный [API](https://api.fssp.gov.ru/).

```
curl "https://is-node3.fssp.gov.ru/ajax_search?callback=jQuery3400961761604239515_1663428296297&system=ip&is^%^5Bextended^%^5D=1&nocache=1&is^%^5Bvariant^%^5D=3&is^%^5Bregion_id^%^5D^%^5B0^%^5D=-1&is^%^5Blast_name^%^5D=&is^%^5Bfirst_name^%^5D=&is^%^5Bdrtr_name^%^5D=^%^D0^%^BA^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^BC^%^D0^%^B5^%^D1^%^82^%^D0^%^B0&is^%^5Bip_number^%^5D=75286^%^2F21^%^2F02068-^%^D0^%^98^%^D0^%^9F&is^%^5Bpatronymic^%^5D=&is^%^5Bdate^%^5D=&is^%^5Baddress^%^5D=&is^%^5Bid_number^%^5D=&is^%^5Bid_type^%^5D^%^5B0^%^5D=&is^%^5Bid_issuer^%^5D=&is^%^5Binn^%^5D=&_=1663428296310" ^
  -H "Accept: */*" ^
  -H "Accept-Language: ru,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8" ^
  -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" ^
  -H "Connection: keep-alive" ^
  -H "DNT: 1" ^
  -H "Pragma: no-cache" ^
  -H "Referer: https://fssp.gov.ru/" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Dest: script" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors" ^
  -H "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.5005.167 YaBrowser/22.7.5.1027 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua: ^\^" Not A;Brand^\^";v=^\^"99^\^", ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"102^\^", ^\^"Yandex^\^";v=^\^"22^\^"" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0" ^
  -H "sec-ch-ua-platform: ^\^"Windows^\^"" ^
  --compressed
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что технически сервер отдает html страницу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте сформировать запрос через chrome dev tools:
Network -> единственный запрос -> ПКМ -> copy -> as PowerShell / CURL

Comment: https://imgur.com/YtTw6Lx
При открытие ссылки в браузере, отдается js.
Проверьте, пожалуйста.
А если например с php file_get_contents(URL), то вернётся html документ(начинается с <!DOCTYPE html>).

Comment: На скриншоте Вам как раз вернулся JS с капчей, а не HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Через VBScript работает, выдаёт JS.
Код скрипта:

```vbs
Set xhr = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xhr.Open "GET", "https://is-node3.fssp.gov.ru/ajax_search?callback=jQuery3400961761604239515_1663428296297&system=ip&is^%^5Bextended^%^5D=1&nocache=1&is^%^5Bvariant^%^5D=3&is^%^5Bregion_id^%^5D^%^5B0^%^5D=-1&is^%^5Blast_name^%^5D=&is^%^5Bfirst_name^%^5D=&is^%^5Bdrtr_name^%^5D=^%^D0^%^BA^%^D0^%^BE^%^D0^%^BC^%^D0^%^B5^%^D1^%^82^%^D0^%^B0&is^%^5Bip_number^%^5D=75286^%^2F21^%^2F02068-^%^D0^%^98^%^D0^%^9F&is^%^5Bpatronymic^%^5D=&is^%^5Bdate^%^5D=&is^%^5Baddress^%^5D=&is^%^5Bid_number^%^5D=&is^%^5Bid_type^%^5D^%^5B0^%^5D=&is^%^5Bid_issuer^%^5D=&is^%^5Binn^%^5D=&_=1663428296310", false
xhr.Send
Set file = fs.OpenTextFile("code.js", 2, true)
file.Write xhr.responseText
file.Close
```

Полученный javascript сохраняется в файл code.js, откуда его можно достать уже чем угодно.